# Help solving a problem about multivariable chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

[image]

Hi! I had some questions regarding this exercise. I was wondering if it is possible for me to do it in two different ways:

**First way**: I calculate the Jacobians for each of the functions, so then I multiply   $D(V(c(t)))\cdot D(c(t))$. But, how do I calculate this:  D(V(c(t))), because I know how to get to $D(V(x,y,z))$ but not to $D(V(c(t)))$.

**Second way**:
And  the other way I was thinking, but I'm not sure about it, consists on defining:
$$
\begin{align}
x(t) &= e^{t^2} \\
y(t) &= e^{-t^2} \\
z(t) &= \log(1+t^2) \\
\end{align}
$$
And then applying the Chain Rule to $V(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. However, I'm not sure if this is a valid way of doing it.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: $V\circ c$ is constant.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with it is constant? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways work, but (2) gives you immediately that the answer is zero: $x(t) y(t) $ is independent of $t$ so differentiating it gives zero.

For (1) you have
\begin{equation}
DV(x(t),...) = (2x y^2,2x^2y,0)|_{x=x(t),...}= 
(2e^{-t^2},2 e^{t^2},0)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
DC= (2t e^{t^2}, ,-2t e^{-t^2},...)
\end{equation}
did not compute the last component as we don't need it: DV is  a row vector, DC is a column vector, so multiplying them gives
\begin{equation}
4t -4t+0=0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you! But I didn't get what you said at the beginning. I think I might know what you mean but I'm not sure... Is it that if I substitute x(t) and y(t) in V(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = (xy)^2  I already get 1 so then that derivative will always be zero?  And thank you!

Comment: Yes tthat's it!